# Flink - how to export flink's kafka connector offsets via JMX Reporter?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

According to [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html), I enable JMX Exporter's and was able to connect to it to see some metrics: jobmanager.Status, jobmanager.job.

```
metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 8789
```

However, I did not see metrics of KafkaConnector (commitedOffets, currentOffsets). **How do I do this?**

I want to get those offset from Flink to calculate

> consumer lag = latest kafka partitions offsets - flink partition offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. JMX port config in **flink-conf.yaml** should be a range (9250-9260), not 1 port number. Flink needs at least 2 ports to export metrics for JobManager and TaskManager at the same time.

```
metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 9250-9260
```

If only 1 port is specified (8789 as in the question), only metrics from JobManager is exported. Metrics of KafkaConnector belong to TaskManager's metrics hence will not appear.